# Is it possible to embed PowerBi report inside Azure dashboard

Tags: azure, powerbi

Is there any way to embed the PowerBI report inside an Azure dashboard. I want to be able to see the report from the Azure dashboard itself and not navigate to PowerBi desktop or cloud version to see the report.

Comment: Looks like yes: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all. You can check it on Power Bi Service, Sharepoint site or embedd it on another custom app.